# Inheritance - args and kwargs

Tags: python, inheritance

I follow some tutorial https://testdriven.io/blog/django-channels/#add-channels-consumer and I wonder why the arguments of super().**init**() function do not have asterisk and double asterisk, is it correct like in the example below?

```
    class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(args, kwargs)
            self.room_name = None
            self.room = None
```

Comment: That depends on the `__init__` of `WebsocketConsumer` class. Looking at the available code, it seems like the parent's constructor takes a sequence as first argument, and a dictionary as 2nd argument. And if that's the case, the code mentioned is absolutely fine.

Comment: no, its not right to me

Comment: then signature of `WebsocketConsumer` would not be like `*args, **kwargs`, so that's why it not right to me.

Comment: base on a answr below, so it seem that anything you throw at the wall basically will stick. so why not how you are doing it, that's totally right on. or even if empty like, `_init_(...)`, that'll also work, no problemo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug or a typo.  Here's the definition of `WebsocketConsumer`: https://github.com/django/channels/blob/f162a4b0e3bec0f0dcf357f24f05ac5d8a15f21a/channels/generic/websocket.py#L14

That said, it doesn't actually use any `__init__` arguments.

Comment: so that nice, so it's ok how OP is doing it because to send it as wrong arguments is still *right*. huh, like catch 22. so basically anything you throw at it will work, because it doesn't even check what's coming. intresting bit for sure.